# Degrees of freedom for a model?

Tags: degrees-of-freedom

When I was reading a project paper, I came across this phrase:

> particularly if you have a lot of data and a model without many degrees of freedom.

What is meant by a model without many degrees of freedom?

I have gone through this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom), but the thread just gives a general definition for df.

Comment: That refers to the number of free parameters that can be adjusted while fitting the model.

Comment: @DLDahly I have updated a question.

Comment: @MarcClaesen - Could elaborate the answer.

Comment: Examples: a multiple regression model has as many degrees of freedom as there are parameters to be estimated, which is equal to the number of regressors (the intercept and the error variance may or may not count, but that is just a minor detail). ARMA model has $p+q$ degrees of freedom where $p$ is the autoregressive lag order and $q$ is the moving-average lag order (again, intercept and error variance may be included in the count). A "model without many degrees of freedom" is similar to a "parsimonious model".

Comment: @RichardHardy - So degrees of freedom are number of paramters. am I right?

Comment: It depends on the context. In the quote that you provided it is so (at least in the simple cases that first come to my mind).

Comment: @RichardHardy- now I got the concept. but in an equation such as x+y+z = 12 , the degrees of freedom is 3(n-1). So this is what is confusing me.

Comment: Your question is based on the implausible claim that a long thread, with many highly voted answers, which deals extensively at many levels with the concept of DF, "just gives a general definition." I would like to suggest that thread deserves more of your attention.